# Expand RAM on Micromax Canvas A76- Android 4.2.2

Tags: ram

I want to use my SDcard to expand my RAM. I am falling short of RAM memory and due to which I need at least 500 MB more RAM space. For this, I have a class10 8 GB microSD card. Can anyone suggest how do I expand my RAM on my device. If any efficient apps are available in the Play Store, please let me know.

P.S. I am a new Android user.

Suggestions and help are always welcome! :)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Abhinav! First suggestion: Make the title and the text of your question match. What are you after: rooting your device, as the title suggests? Or "expanding your RAM"? → Assuming the latter, make that the title. If it turns out it requires rooting your device (which it certainly will), make that a second (separate) question (SE sites are Q&A sites, which work best using one question per post).

Comment: Thanks @Izzy! Point noted! I guess I have to go for rooting my device in either way. But, can you tell me if creating swap spaces in my memory card will really help in easing the burden over the RAM?

Comment: That might depend. Helpful resources: [questions on swapper](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=swapper+is%3Aquestion) / [questions tagged "swap"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swap). Studying those, you might get an idea about before/after conditions as well as possible side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expand your RAM to SDcard!
Instead you could create [swap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970421/difference-between-virtual-memory-and-swap-space) in sdcard.

You could use applications like [Swapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.azasoft.free.swapper&hl=en) from google play store. The device must be rooted to do that.

Swap space may not be as fast as RAM.

Comment: How will creating swap space reduce burden over my device's RAM? If possible, could you please explain the usage of this swap space in context of Android environment?

Comment: For that, you also might wish to see [Why don't most Android devices have swap area as typical OS does?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17478196/2533433). It *might* help in some cases; but there's most likely a reason why it's not "built-in" by default.